# Map response string to an Object from POST request

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to write a function that makes a Post requests and it returns as body data a person object. Normally would be used GET operation for this, but I am constrained to use POST because some technicalities.

```
   // HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public async Task<Person> PersonService()
    {
      var bodyObj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      bodyObj ["user_id"] = "ac345adf3gj6";
      var serializedData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(bodyObj);
      var stringContet = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
      var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
      var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      // map content to person object
      return person; // object mapped from content string
    }
```

Is there any way to wait for the data, map the string to a Person object and then return it as a Person object and not as a Task?

Something along these lines

```
 public Person PersonService() { ... return person; }
```

Comment: .NET 6 has HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync and HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync methods. There's no reason to manually serialize or deserialize strings, or use dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deserialize the content from JSON, you can use the [ReadFromJsonAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.httpcontentjsonextensions.readfromjsonasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-json-httpcontentjsonextensions-readfromjsonasync-1(system-net-http-httpcontent-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-system-threading-cancellationtoken))-method:

```
public async Task<Person> PersonService()
{
  var bodyObj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  bodyObj ["user_id"] = "ac345adf3gj6";
  var serializedData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(bodyObj);
  var stringContet = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
  // Change the following line: 
  var person = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Person>();
  return person; // object mapped from content string
}
```

Comment: You can use `PostAsJsonAsync` to remove the first part of the code too, reducing the method to just two lines. The string can be replaced with `new {user_id="ac345adf3gj6"}`